# Mongoose populate by ObjectId where there is another property after the ObjectId in the schema as well

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a `Cart` Schema as defined below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const cartSchema = new Schema({
    items:[
        {
            id:{
                type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref:'Post'
            },
            quantity:Number
        }
    ]
});
```

The Schema references the `_id` of another Schema of `Post` within the `items` array, as well as a quantity of that item in the cart. My find statement for the `Cart` includes a `populate()` method call to theoretically bring in the actual `Post` item so I can show the title, etc. on the page:

```
let cart;
if(!req.session.cartId) {
    req.session.error = 'There are no items currently in your cart';
    return res.redirect('/');
}
try {
    cart = await Cart.findById(req.session.cartId).populate({
        path:'item',
        model:'Post'
    }).exec();
```

Leaving out the `catch` block because I don't believe it's part of the issue. 
I should be able to see the `Post` document in place of its `ObjectId`, and I've been able to do things like this in other places.

The statement runs and returns the Cart, but it seems like the `populate()` call is being ignored, and all I get back is the `items` array with the `_id` and `quantity` values exactly as I stored them originally:

```
cart: {
  _id: 5e6e884ffda1be0648ae1b99,
  items: [ { _id: 5e3435f9ab899a1dd8a4105e, quantity: 1 } ],
  __v: 1
}
```

However, everything I'm seeing regarding `Mongoose.populate()` is storing *only* the reference to the `ObjectId` of the foreign (post) document within the current (cart) document, without the additional property of `quantity`. Is that what's causing me problems? If so, how can I link the quantity of the `Post` within `items` within `Cart`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aren't populating correctly.

Your path must be `items.id` instead of `item`, and model must be the actual model, not a string, so remove the single quotes, and be sure you import it like `const Post = require("../models/post");`

```js
 cart = await Cart.findById(req.session.cartId).populate({
        path:'items.id',
        model:Post
    }).exec();
```

This will give you a result like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5e6f2dd63d82e35988921907",
    "items": [
        {
            "_id": "5e6f2dd63d82e35988921909",
            "id": {
                "_id": "5e6f2da53d82e35988921905",
                "title": "Post 1 Title",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e6f2dd63d82e35988921908",
            "id": {
                "_id": "5e6f2db13d82e35988921906",
                "title": "Post 2 Title",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "quantity": 2
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

The result looks a little ugly because of the id field, not easy to read.
So I advise you to rename the `items.id` field to `items.post` like this:

```js
const cartSchema = new Schema({
  items: [
    {
      post: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Post"
      },
      quantity: Number
    }
  ]
});
```

And change the populate path to the `items.post` so that result look like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5e6f2dd63d82e35988921907",
    "items": [
        {
            "_id": "5e6f2dd63d82e35988921909",
            "post": {
                "_id": "5e6f2da53d82e35988921905",
                "title": "Post 1 Title",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e6f2dd63d82e35988921908",
            "post": {
                "_id": "5e6f2db13d82e35988921906",
                "title": "Post 2 Title",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "quantity": 2
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: That mostly worked! I followed your advice and changed the `id` property to `post` in the model, instead, and changed the `populate` call to `items.post`. Also had to go update my controller to add an item to the cart to reference `item.post`. One thing that didn't need to change was the `model` value in `populate`, removing the quotes. I think it works because the `Post` model is referenced in the `Cart` model itself. Should we edit that part?

Comment: @RGreenstreet did you get the result you wanted?

Comment: I sure did! Now I can use that to populate the EJS file for the cart.